# ErrorType: undefined is not a function (node)

Tags: javascript, node.js

Hi i have a little problem, a console send me this error: ErrorType: undefined is not a function, var server = http.createSever(function(request, reposne). Can you help me? This is my 1st post in this website. 
This is a code:

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var mime = require('mime');
var cache = {};


function send404(response){
  response.writeHead(404, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  response.write('Błąd 404');
  response.end();
}


function sendFile(response, filePath, fileContent){
  response.writeHead(
    200,
    {"content-type": mime.lookup(path.basename(filePath))}
  );
  response.end(fileContent);
}

function serverStatic(response, cache, absPath){
  if(cache[absPath]){
    sendFile(response, absPath, cache[absPath]);
  }
  else {
    fs.exists(abs.Path, function(exists){
      if(exists){
        fs.readFile(absPath, function(err, data){
          if(err){
            send404(response);
          }
          else {
            cache[absPath] = data;
            sendFile(response, absPath, data);
          }
        });
      }
      else {
        send404(response);
      }
    });
  }
}


var server = http.createSever(function(request, reposne){
  var filePath = false;

  if(request.url == '/'){
    filePath = 'public/index.html';
  }
  else {
    filePath = 'public' + request.url;
  }

  var absPath = './'+filePath;
  serverStatic(response, cache, absPath);
});

server.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log("port 3000");
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's `createServer`, not `createSever` (note the `r` before the `v`).